# onBackPressed from Fragment Displays Activity Twice

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onbackpressed, dialogfragment

I have an Application min SDK 21, target 25. Using : `android.app.DialogFragment` and `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.`

The initial `Activity` is a Launcher it can launch 1 of 3 Activities and 1 `DialogFragment`. The `DialogFragment` can in turn launch an `Activity` (which is one of the 3 Activities). The problem that I have is only with regard to the `DialogFragment` being loaded and that Fragment then loading an Application and then returning to the Launcher.

When the `Fragment` returns immediately to the Launcher (without loading the `Activity`), this works OK. I can detect that the `Fragment` was loaded via the launcher and `onBackPress()` handles it OK.

However, when the `Fragment` loads another `Activity` and then `onBackPress()`is used to return to the `Fragment` and then `onBackPress()`is used to return to the Launcher, I have a problem. The way this situation is currently handled is that the `Fragment` loads the Launcher via an `Intent` using the flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` (this appeared to be a solution to someone’s similar problem). I have tried other variations of these flags and also without these flags. I have also tried to use for this situation `onBackPress()`in the `DialogFragment` without loading the `Activity` using an Intent, and the Application terminates, and I need it to return to the Launcher.

In this case, using these flags, when I return to the Launcher, the Launcher displays and then clears and then redisplays (on another `onBackPress()`, the Application then terminates correctly). The problem is with the Launcher displaying twice. I presume that the Launcher that displays first is the original copy loaded and then it is replaced by a new copy. I have not found a way (in this scenario) in which to load the original copy of the Launcher (if that is in fact what is happening). As stated, this is a `DialogFragment`.

How can I solve this so that the Launcher Activity does not display twice in this situation?

Comment: Post the code that you have tried Please

Comment: how you have created DialogFragment ? Post the code here.

Comment: Show us the architecture. This should be a simple solution but if the steps and calling of activities and handling back events is wrongly implemented then this turns up. I had a similar problem a few years ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't just finish the activity within the fragment to return to the launcher activity?

If you really have to use a intent, try Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Comment: The Launcher Axtivity is the Activity that loaded the fragment. Therefore, I don't think that finishing the Activity within the Fragment would work. Your second suggection however does appear to work. I'll continue testing this program because it is new, and if all's well, I'll tick your answer in a couple of days.

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the `onBackPressed()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 1) {
        finish();
    } else {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
   getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
} 
else {
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

use this in `onBackPressed()` method.